# Ajax and json issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a little ajax call to load json data into the DOM but it's not working. When I look at the net tab I see that its loaded but no data is on the actual page. It just says [object Object]

```
   $.getJSON('json/redstone.json', function(data) {
   var items = [];

   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
   });

   $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'my-new-list',
       html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('body');
   });
```

Here is my JSON

```
{
"allconfig": {
    "card.inserted": {
        "value": "Not Inserted",
            "type": "enum",
            "range": "",
            "clone": false,
            "archive": false,
            "access": "R"
    },
        "card.cisproc": {
        "value": "Processed",
            "type": "string",
            "range": "",
            "clone": false,
            "archive": false,
            "access": "R"
    },
        "card.mfgid": {
        "value": "",
            "type": "string",
            "range": "",
            "clone": false,
            "archive": false,
            "access": "R"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have objects within your object, so the value in the each loop is still an object and not a string, you would need to iterate more or specify a certain object property that contains a string as objects can't be inserted into the DOM, then all you get is Object, Object.

Comment: I kind of see what your saying, but Im not sure what my code change should be.

Comment: try this keyword ....items.push('<li id="' + this.key + '">' + this.val + '</li>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is actually an object in your JSON data. And if you do `$.each` over the `data`, you will only get the `allconfig` element. So you might want to enumerate over `data.allconfig` instead.

So you might want to display the `val`'s `value` property instead, like this:

```
$.getJSON('json/redstone.json', function(data) {
var items = [];

$.each(data.allconfig, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.value + '</li>');
});

$('<ul/>', {
   'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
   }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybjgr/)

Comment: That gives me "undefined" in the web page instead of the data in the json.

Comment: Modified my answer, I've also tested it on a local server with your data and it works.

Comment: @popnoodles: I start enumerating at `data.allconfig`.

Comment: Great that works, but its not showing the other data (type, range,clone, archive and access)

Comment: then you can add those values to the markup in `items.push()` like this: `val.type`, `val.range`, `val.clone`, `val.archive`, etc... Just like I did with `val.value`

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can try is iterating over the JSON object using regular javascript iteration, like so:

```
for(var key in data){
    var value = data[key];
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + value + '</li>');
}
```

**Edit**: I just realized your data structure, as someone pointed out in the comments, has sub, or nested objects. My method, by itself, will only work for the first level of key:value pairs. If you'd like to make your iteration function a little more generic, you can use recursion to properly dive through your structure, like so:

```
function buildData(data){
    for(var key in data){
        var value = data[key];
        if(typeof(value) == "object"){
          nestedData = buildData(value);
          items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + nested + '</li>');
          // I'm not sure how you want to handle your nested objects, so place
          // here what you need and whatever else you need to do to handle
          // your nested object situation.
        }else{
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + value + '</li>');
        }
    }
}
```